# ac both sides have high pressure

Tags: ac, dodge, ram

04 dodge ram 1500. High side goes to 390 and pressure switch cuts off compressor. Low side comes up to 65 until compreesor shuts down. Cools while driving fairly we'll. Begins blowing hot when stopped for about 30 seconds. Will begin to blow cool after going again.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the fan kicking on when the compressor goes?

Comment: Does not have electric fan. Fan clutch is working.

Comment: Do you have a shroud in place around the fan? Your description lends to a problem with the fan not working properly from a lack of air getting pulled through the condenser when the vehicle is sitting still.